# Problems after installing Microsoft Services for UNIX

Tags: windows-7, bash, unix, cygwin, windows-services

I had Cygwin installed and everything worked liked a charm. At some point I installed Microsoft Services for UNIX on my computer and the problems started.

- When I open up a commnad shell an wanna try the new functionality and type for example vi, the answer is:

  - PSXSS.EXE - Entry Point Not Found : The procedure entry point TFLFreeUserThreadStack could not be located in the dynamic link library ntdll.dll.
- When I try to open cygwin, it tells me:

  - /bin/bash: No such file or directory

When I connect an external Hard drive it needs 30' to detect it.

I tried to rollback to an earlier restore point. Which didn't really help. When installing SFU I agreed to case-senstive file system - Was this the cause and if so how can I reverse it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

yours

magu_

OS: Win 7 / 32 - Bit

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using the commmand shell for Cygwin you can take all the DLL's for this product along with all the commands you want to leverage and place them all in one directory.  Then add the directory to the path if you want.  It looks like the MS Unix stuff overwrote some settings in the registry.  If you're using X11 as well, you may just want to re-install it over the MS Unix stuff and see if that works.

Comment: Joe: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that i cannot roll back/uninstall. Meaning that I cannot come back. To overcome all this issues I played over a an Ubuntu (not engough space for dual boot) and now I have a computer for all my windows stuff and an old laptop for all my linux stuff. Seems to be the better solution so far.

Comment: Not uninstall.  Reinstall Cygwin again.